# ¿Porque la consulta siempre me devuelve empty?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

estoy haciendo un trabajo de un software gestor de una biblioteca, y necesito hacer que cuando empiezo a escribir el nombre del autor se vaya actualizando el DataGrid con los datos de los autores cuyo nombre contenga esas letras que escribo. Y el problema es que siempre me devuelve vacio como si no hubiese autores con esas letras. El problema estoy casi seguro de que es el comando de la consulta, pero he buscado un monton y no he encontrado como solucionarlo. Les dejo el comando:

```
SELECT * FROM autores WHERE Contains (nombre, '%"+unAutor.nombreAutor+"%');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador like busca un patrón en la columna, el comodín `%` significa -cualquier cosa-. Así la consulta siguiente busca una parte del nombre del autor dentro de la columna sin importar su posición.

```
SELECT * FROM autores WHERE nombre like '%nombreAutor%';
```